# How do ML model retain/store the learning(s)?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, supervised-learning

In other words, if the model after training and testing is ready for making future predictions, it must be storing the learning(s) somewhere in memory or disk or cache (or I really don't know).

So, where (how) is it exactly stored?

Hope I asked my doubt clearly for experts to advise.

Answer (score 2):

After generating a **predictive** model by fitting the data with `model.fit(X,y)` , "the learnings" are simply coefficients (weights ) that are multiplied by the features ( **X** ) to give you a certain **y**. In other words, in the end, what you get is a **function** that for an input **X** returns a **y**, you can store the model on the disk using a **joblib or pickle** and load it in another environment. machine learning? more like coefficients learning.

Note : This could be edited in case my answer is lacking more details

Comment: Ah! Brilliant. I never thought about it this way. Is it like you form a mathematical equation `f(a,b) = ax+b` where just need to pass `a` and `b` ? So, the main thing internally the ML algo does is finding the best equation (or function as you call)?

Comment: yes more or less, that's basically machine learning in a nutshell. Once you learn a,b for many x's that are your training data, you can use the coefficients to predict the y for similar x's that are unseen for your model.

Comment: Great. How does the machine determine if the function will be `f(a,b)=ax+b` or `f(a,b)=a^2.x^3+14.b` or `f(a,b,c)=a.x^2+32.b+4.c`

Comment: that's the data scientist's job to determine the 'hypthotesis' depending on the problem and the data, the hypothesis is the function that's most likely going to explain the 'y' ( linear, non-linear etc..) and to know what are the X's that explain 'y' best. and then the learning starts!

Answer (score 1):

When you do linear regression (ordinary least squares) you calculate:

$$ (X'X)^{-1} X'y=\beta. $$

Here $X$ are your features and $y$ is the target. The vector $\beta$ are the coefficients which you can use to make predictions on new data. So saving a model in this simple setup just means to store a list of floats. Easy!

With more complex models, e.g. neural nets, you usually have (much) more coefficients (or weights), but the general idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer that I can given to you is you can save your entire model or you can save only your weights of your module in hdf5 format or json format. After that you can load your model anytime form disk to memory. But the way you save your model may differ from the machine learning library that you are using. If you are using Tensorflow or keras [here how to do it](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_restore_models) follow this link you will meet their official documentation. Anyway you could reach this simple explanation by doing a simple Google search too..